# Running OpenShift OKD 3.10 with Vagrant and Ansible - Connection refused

Tags: ansible, vagrant, openshift, virtualbox, okd

I've been trying for days now to get Openshift running on a single virtual machine set up by Vagrant and using ansible to install. I've been through alot of github issues of openshift-ansible but still no luck at the end. This is how far i got. So I started off with my Vagrantfile and using CentosOS/7 as box. As they appearantly switched the file system from xfs this is the first error I got as docker wouldn't want to work. So I looked up the changelog of the VM-Box Centos and downgraded to V1804.02. So this is the Vagrantfile I have now

**Vagrantfile**

```
$lab_openshift = <<SCRIPT
yum -y update
yum install -y epel-release git docker httpd-tools java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless
yum install -y ansible python-passlib
systemctl start docker
systemctl enable docker
git clone -b release-3.10 https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible /root/openshift-ansible
ssh-keygen -f /root/.ssh/id_rsa -N ''
cp /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
ssh-keyscan 172.24.0.11 >> .ssh/known_hosts
cp .ssh/known_hosts /root/.ssh/known_hosts
ssh-copy-id -f -i /root/.ssh/id_rsa root@172.24.0.11
cp /home/vagrant/etc.ansible.hosts /etc/ansible/hosts
cp /home/vagrant/etc.selinux.config /etc/selinux/config

reboot
SCRIPT

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.vm.define "openshift" do |conf|
    # conf.vm.box = "peru/my_centos-7-x86_64"
    # conf.vm.box_version = "20181211.01"
    conf.vm.box = "centos/7"
    config.vm.box_version = "1804.02"
    conf.vm.hostname = 'openshift.example.com'
    conf.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.24.0.11"
    conf.vm.provision "file", source: "./etc.ansible.hosts", destination: "~/etc.ansible.hosts"
    conf.vm.provision "file", source: "./etc.selinux.config", destination: "~/etc.selinux.config"
    conf.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 6144
        v.cpus = 2
    end
    conf.vm.provision "shell", inline: $lab_openshift
 end
end
```

As you'll get errors with SELinux enforced or disabled this is the config for SELinux

**SELinux Conf**

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

Now i started of with the ansible hosts.localhost from the inventory. The first error I got was on the docker_image_availability check. On GitHub ppl said you should just disable it. So this was the first change. But you'll still run into some problems via install (Error message Control plane pods didn't come up). So the next change was to change the osm_etcd_image to osm_etcd_image=registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/etcd according to some github issues which leaves me with the current ansible hosts file

**Hosts**

```
#bare minimum hostfile

[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd

[OSEv3:vars]

osm_etcd_image=registry.access.redhat.com/rhel7/etcd
openshift_deployment_type=origin
openshift_release=v3.10
openshift_portal_net=172.30.0.0/16
openshift_disable_check=disk_availability,memory_availability,docker_image_availability

openshift_node_groups=[{'name': 'node-config-all-in-one', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true', 'node-role.kubernetes.io/infra=true', 'node-role.kubernetes.io/compute=true']}]


[masters]
172.24.0.11 ansible_connection=local

[etcd]
172.24.0.11 ansible_connection=local

[nodes]
# openshift_node_group_name should refer to a dictionary with matching key of name in list openshift_node_groups.
172.24.0.11 ansible_connection=local openshift_node_group_name="node-config-all-in-one"
```

Unfortunately I still won't get the cluster to run as it fails retrying over and over again

**/bin/oc get pod master-etcd-openshift.example.com -o json -n kube-system"**

which seems to refuse the connection and leaves me with this error message

> The connection to the server openshift.example.com:8443 was refused -
>   did you specify the right host or port?\n"

Now I just found some unsanswered github issues on that error and am finally stuck. Maybe somebody has an idea what I am doing wrong.

[edit]

oh any my etc/hosts is extended with
`172.24.0.11 openshift.example.com` 
and pinging either 172.24.0.11 and openshift.example.com is successfull

One more thing worth mentioning is that docker conttainer list -a will also tell me that one container keeps trying to restart but fails to do so

> ab4651c81600        96f98d080ffd    "/bin/bash -c '#!/..."   About a minute ago   Exited (255) 35 seconds ago    k8s_api_master-api-openshift.example.com_kube-system_fabe879b27fee405485858817f14f32f_9

So this is pretty much what is described in this issue https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/9894 however I cannot figure out what is wrong with my config

[/edit]

[edit2]

```
The log of the k8s_api_master container is also not really helping me out

I1224 11:46:42.874204       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "NamespaceLifecycle"
I1224 11:46:42.874390       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "Initializers"
I1224 11:46:42.874400       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "ValidatingAdmissionWebhook"
I1224 11:46:42.874408       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "MutatingAdmissionWebhook"
I1224 11:46:42.874420       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "AlwaysAdmit"
I1224 11:46:42.874425       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "AlwaysPullImages"
I1224 11:46:42.874432       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "LimitPodHardAntiAffinityTopology"
I1224 11:46:42.874440       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "DefaultTolerationSeconds"
I1224 11:46:42.874446       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "AlwaysDeny"
I1224 11:46:42.874458       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "EventRateLimit"
I1224 11:46:42.874465       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "DenyEscalatingExec"
I1224 11:46:42.874470       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "DenyExecOnPrivileged"
I1224 11:46:42.874477       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "ExtendedResourceToleration"
I1224 11:46:42.874483       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "OwnerReferencesPermissionEnforcement"
I1224 11:46:42.874495       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "ImagePolicyWebhook"
I1224 11:46:42.874503       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "InitialResources"
I1224 11:46:42.874509       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "LimitRanger"
I1224 11:46:42.874517       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "NamespaceAutoProvision"
I1224 11:46:42.874524       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "NamespaceExists"
I1224 11:46:42.874530       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "NodeRestriction"
I1224 11:46:42.874538       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "PersistentVolumeLabel"
I1224 11:46:42.874544       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "PodNodeSelector"
I1224 11:46:42.874552       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "PodPreset"
I1224 11:46:42.874559       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "PodTolerationRestriction"
I1224 11:46:42.874566       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "ResourceQuota"
I1224 11:46:42.874573       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "PodSecurityPolicy"
I1224 11:46:42.874579       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "Priority"
I1224 11:46:42.874590       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "SecurityContextDeny"
I1224 11:46:42.874598       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "ServiceAccount"
I1224 11:46:42.874604       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "DefaultStorageClass"
I1224 11:46:42.874611       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "PersistentVolumeClaimResize"
I1224 11:46:42.874619       1 plugins.go:84] Registered admission plugin "StorageObjectInUseProtection"
F1224 11:47:12.886869       1 start_api.go:68] dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused
```

[/edit2]

Comment: Without knowing what the logs were from the `k8s_api_master-api-openshift.example.com_kube-system_fabe879b27fee405485858817f14f32f_9` container, it's impossible to say what exactly you need to fix

Comment: added the log. not really helping me out too much either

Comment: "127.0.0.1:2379: connect: connection refused" means it is looking for `etcd` on 127.0.0.1 which is almost certainly wrong. Without studying the playbooks it would be hard to know what caused that error, but you can certainly look in the thing that launched `k8s_api_master` and see some of the rest of its command line flags in order to help you track it down

Comment: ok that brings me a little closer so i found this issue https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible/issues/7379 and reconfigured etc/hosts and replaced 127.0.0.1 with 172.24.0.11. yet in the logs also this connection gets refused. i also tried to disable the firewall but still no luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, it took a lot of work but I finally found out what the problem was. It's basically that your localhosts has to point to the ip you define in your vagrantfile. otherwise it will not work. This is controlled in the etc/hosts. I'm also using hawkular metrics. If you don't want to you also won't need to install java-18.0-openjdk-headless

**Vagrantfile**

```
$lab_openshift = <<SCRIPT
yum -y update

yum install -y epel-release
echo "==================Installing PYTHON=================="
yum install -y python-pip python-devel python python-passlib

echo "==================Installing GIT=================="
yum install -y git

echo "==================Installing ANSIBLE=================="
yum install -y ansible

echo "==================Installing java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless================="
yum install -y java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless

cp /home/vagrant/etc.ansible.hosts /etc/ansible/hosts
cp /home/vagrant/etc.selinux.config /etc/selinux/config
cp /home/vagrant/etc.hosts /etc/hosts

git clone -b release-3.10 https://github.com/openshift/openshift-ansible /root/openshift-ansible


reboot
SCRIPT


Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
 config.vm.define "openshift" do |conf|
    conf.vm.box = "centos/7"
    config.vm.box_version = "1804.02"
    conf.vm.hostname = 'openshift.example.com'
    conf.vm.network "private_network", ip: "172.24.0.11"
    conf.vm.provision "file", source: "./etc.ansible.hosts", destination: "~/etc.ansible.hosts"
    conf.vm.provision "file", source: "./etc.selinux.config", destination: "~/etc.selinux.config"
    conf.vm.provision "file", source: "./etc.hosts", destination: "~/etc.hosts"
    conf.vm.provider "virtualbox" do |v|
        v.memory = 6144
        v.cpus = 2
    end
    conf.vm.provision "shell", inline: $lab_openshift
 end
end
```

**SELinux Config (etc.selinux.config)**

```
SELINUX=permissive
```

**etc/ansible/hosts (etc.ansible.hosts)**

```
[OSEv3:children]
masters
nodes
etcd

[OSEv3:vars]

openshift_ip=172.24.0.11

openshift_deployment_type=origin
openshift_disable_check=memory_availability,disk_availability

ansible_service_broker_install=false
openshift_master_cluster_hostname=172.24.0.11
openshift_master_cluster_public_hostname=openshift.example.com
openshift_hostname=172.24.0.11
openshift_public_hostname=openshift.example.com
openshift_metrics_install_metrics=true
openshift_metrics_image_version=v3.10
openshift_master_default_subdomain=openshift.example.com

openshift_disable_check=disk_availability,memory_availability,docker_image_availability

    openshift_node_groups=[{'name': 'node-config-all-in-one', 'labels': ['node-role.kubernetes.io/master=true', 'node-role.kubernetes.io/infra=true', 'node-role.kubernetes.io/compute=true']}]


[masters]
172.24.0.11 ansible_connection=local

[etcd]
172.24.0.11 ansible_connection=local

[nodes]
172.24.0.11 ansible_connection=local openshift_node_group_name="node-config-all-in-one"
```

**/etc/hosts (etc.hosts)**

```
172.24.0.11    localhost   openshift.example.com   openshift
::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```